# Android Application starts from Beginning

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a series of Android activity A-->B-->C-->D while in D if I press the home button and click on the app icon, the app starts from  Activity A, I clear the previous activity and call finish on each activity and I have tried the launch modes Single task and Single instance, but in vain. Please suggest.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is your issue?  That it starts at A instead of D?  Or that the notificaion for D is there?

Comment: Do you launch your app the first time using the app icon? Or do you launch the app the first time from an IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse) or from the installer (after installation via web browser or market)?

Comment: Also, post your manifest

Comment: I start the app using the app icon.  I figured out that the problem was with task affinity in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. The problem was Activity D had a task affinity.
android:taskaffinity="". I removed this statement in Manifest. Now the app shows the Activity from where it was left at.